# Converting between types that use time.Time

Tags: go, time, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a migration script from Jira to GitLab. The [Jira API library](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira#Time) I'm using reads issue creation time from Jira using this type:

```golang
// Time represents the Time definition of JIRA as a time.Time of go
type Time time.Time
```

The [GitLab API client](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab@v0.93.1#CreateIssueOptions) allows creating issues with a creation time using a field of type `*time.Time`.

```golang
type CreateIssueOptions struct {
    CreatedAt                          *time.Time `url:"created_at,omitempty" json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    DueDate                            *ISOTime   `url:"due_date,omitempty" json:"due_date,omitempty"`
    // ...
}
```

How do I convert from the Jira time to the GitLab time? I've been playing around with different options and can't make any sense of how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Jira struct:

```
type SomeStruct struct {
   ...
   T Time
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
tm:=time.Time(someStruct.T)
if !tm.IsZero() {
   createIssue.CreatedAt=&tm
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sample:

```
type Time time.Time
jiraTime := Time(time.Now())  //instead of time.Now(), jiraTime
gitlabTime := (*time.Time)(&jiraTime)
```